# use += several times, changes are reversed c++

Tags: c++, overloading, operator-keyword

I have implemented a class vl_vector and a deriv class vl_string, which is pretty similar to STL vector (vl_string is for chars and handles the '\0' char).
I have overloaded the += operator for char, char * and another vl_string.
declarations:

```
  vl_string<StaticCapacity> operator+=(const vl_string<StaticCapacity>&vs);
  vl_string<StaticCapacity> operator+=(const char *str);
  vl_string<StaticCapacity> operator+=(char c);
```

Functions code:

```
template<size_t StaticCapacity>
vl_string<StaticCapacity> vl_string<StaticCapacity>::operator+= (const char *str)
{
  size_t len = strlen(str);
  //insert string before the '\0' char.
  vl_string<StaticCapacity>::insert(this->end() - 1, str, str + len);
  return *this;
}

template<size_t StaticCapacity>
vl_string<StaticCapacity> vl_string<StaticCapacity>::operator+= (const char c)
{
// push char to the end of string.
  this->push_back (c);
  return *this;
}

template<size_t StaticCapacity>
vl_string<StaticCapacity>
vl_string<StaticCapacity>::operator+= (const vl_string &vs)
{
  auto first = vs.cbegin();
  auto last = vs.cend() - 1; // to not include the '\0' char.
  // iterate over vl_string and insert each char to the end of string.
  while (first != last)
  {
    this->push_back (*first);
    first++;
  }
  return *this;
}
```

I'm trying to run the following code to check my program:

```
vl_string<> vl_str;
vl_string<> vl_str_to_add = "Never gonna";
(((vl_str += vl_str_to_add) += ' ') += "say goodbye") += '\n';
assert(vl_str.contains ("Never gonna say goodbye\n"));
```

I'm following the program in debugger, and everything seems to work. In the end I get a vl_string the contains the full desired string. But when the program reach the end of the line, it calls the destructor and deletes everything except the first operation (vl_str += vl_str_to_add).
Tried several things but I'm pretty stuck, would love an explanation.
thanks!

Comment: Should guess without the code?

Comment: Your `operator+=` returns a new (temporary) `vl_string<StaticCapacity>`, which as you've noticed is immediately destroyed since it is not assigned to a variable.  Your `operator+=` should return a reference to the original (modified) object if you want the operations to be "chainable" like this.

Comment: Although there seems to be an obvious problem here, it is not possible to authoritatively to state it, because the shown code fails to meet Stackoverflow's requirements for a [mre]. It is unlikely that anyone would want to spend a bunch of time explaining what the apparent problem is, only to discover that the overloaded are structured completely differently and the real problem turns out something else, and wasting their time. Please follow Stackoverflow's instructions in the [help] for creating a [mre].

Comment: In this case, there is an obvious problem, so no MCVE necessary. In general, [mcve] is a good idea - if your question turns out to be actually hard to answer, MCVE will help you get answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your functions is that they return a copy of the object, not a reference.

Use

```
vl_string<StaticCapacity>& operator+=(const vl_string<StaticCapacity>&vs);
vl_string<StaticCapacity>& operator+=(const char *str);
vl_string<StaticCapacity>& operator+=(char c);
//                       ^^^ Reference return type.
```

Comment: Maybe, however if they did modify `*this`, the results will be something different, because at least the `vl_str += ...` would've modified `*this`, and this would be shown in the results. Without a [mre] this question cannot really be answered.

Comment: It worked. Thanks! Sorry about not posting enough code, first time here. I'll learn for next time

Comment: @OmriWolf, please post a [mcve] still. That will improve the post for future visitors.